# AEM Sightly Include from /etc/designs

Tags: aem, sightly

I am somewhat new to AEM and Sightly. I have written a 'page' component to house my page content. I have a number of devices with different CSS under `/etc/designs/myapp` as follows:

`/etc/designs/myapp`

```
- /128/style.css
- /240/style.css
```

etc etc..

Back in my page component, I have a number of different HTML files that I use to trigger the correct CSS via a Sling selector. For example:

`/apps/myapp/components/page`

```
- 128.html
- 240.html
```

The purpose of these files is to include the HTML `<head>` section with the CSS as an **inline style** (cannot link to external CSS due to device limitations).

The problem that I am having is that if I place 128/style.css inside the component itself, the include works. If I have it under `/etc/designs/myapp`, I can't get it to include properly. I have tried using `${currentDesign.path @ appendPath='/128/style.css'}` and I have tried explicitly referencing the whole path.

Here is an example of 128.html, under the page component:

```
<html>
<head><!--/*
    */--><div data-sly-include="/libs/wcm/core/components/init/init.jsp" data-sly-unwrap></div><!--/*
    */-->

    <title>${currentPage.title}</title>
        <div data-sly-unwrap data-sly-include="/etc/designs/myapp/128/style.css"></div>
</head>
<body class="main" role="document" data-sly-include="body.html"></body>
</html>
```

I realise that I need a `<style></style>` section wrapping any CSS that is included, but for now, I am just trying to get a page to include from `/etc/designs`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of data-sly-include: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/block-statements.html#include

> data-sly-include: Replaces the content of the host element with the markup generated by the indicated HTML template file (Sightly, JSP, ESP etc.) when it is processed by its corresponding template engine. The rendering context of the included file will not include the current Sightly context (that of the including file); Consequently, for inclusion of Sightly files, the current data-sly-use would have to be repeated in the included file (In such a case it is usually better to use data-sly-template and data-sly-call)

It's not meant to be used for the type of inclusion you are trying to do since you are not calling any renderer. I think you should use client libraries and include your CSS files only, here is the documentation about this : http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/sightly-clientlibs/

You should define a client library category for each of your styles and call the right clientlib when you need it using `<meta data-sly-call="${clientLib.css @ categories='category.style.128'}" data-sly-unwrap></meta>`

Hope this helps.